# How to list a secondment on my resume

Tags: resume

I've been asked by my employer to undertake a secondment to another division. The understanding is my existing role will be filled on a temporary basis by someone else.

Should I note this as:

```
Manager - Secondment Position (2021 - current)
Manager - Main role (2014 - current)
```

or

```
Manager - Secondment Position (2021 - current)
Manager = Main role (2014 - 2021)
```

?

Comment: How different is this from your other role?  The reason for asking is that if it's not really much different, and you don't have a particular reason to highlight it, you might not list it separately.  But if it's different in a way that would be meaningful to future employers - it has more responsibility, it has a different kind of responsibility - then you can list it.  (And - to be clear, you will come back to your original role?)

Comment: Yes returning to original role (at this stage) in 6 months. New role is quite different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done a few secondments and I think it's important to show clearly that you continued in your substantive position while completing the secondment. The format I use is:

> Manager Type 1 2014 - current
>
> - Company X
> - Responsibilities
> - Achievements in the role

And then below that:

> Manager Type 2 (***Secondment***) 2021 - current
>
> - Company X
> - Responsibilities
> - Achievements in the role

This simple format has worked for me for the past 15 years without any confusion.

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to convey?

I am **guessing** you want to say something like:

> i am a manager at company X for 7 years, and my manager likes me so much he asked me to step in the similar role in other division to save their behinds and the whole business

I am not sure if CV is the right place to do it. I would just say "Manager - 2014-current" and use this as an example answer to "what challenging situation you faced at work and how you managed it?"